# Unable to start MariaDB - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I installed mariadb in my system. But I forgot the root password... I tried to reset root password by following "https://tecadmin.net/steps-to-reset-mariadb-root-password-in-linux/" and mysql official documentation.But no success.

But when I install fresh mariadb it is working. As per the official documention,  while we installing mariadb it will ask root password. However in my case, it is never asking. However the server working on fresh install.

When i stop and restart server, it is keep on failing..

The error message I am getting is

> mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.6 database server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
>              └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf    Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2019-07-15 14:52:16 IST; 1min 46s ago
>        Docs: man:mysqld(8)
>              https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/   Process: 10988 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER
>   $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process:
>   10829 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] &&
>   VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && syst
>   Process: 10827 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment
>   _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 10826 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d
>   /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 10988
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Status: "MariaDB server is down"
>
> Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15 14:52:16 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Starting shutdown... Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]:
>   2019-07-15 14:52:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned
>   error. Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15 14:52:16 0
>   [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. Jul
>   15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15 14:52:16 0 [Note] Plugin
>   'FEEDBACK' is disabled. Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15
>   14:52:16 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may
>   be not loaded Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15 14:52:16
>   0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins. Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu
>   mysqld[10988]: 2019-07-15 14:52:16 0 [ERROR] Aborting Jul 15 14:52:16
>   sonu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu systemd[1]: mariadb.service:
>   Failed with result 'timeout'. Jul 15 14:52:16 sonu systemd[1]: Failed
>   to start MariaDB 10.4.6 database server.

Please guide me towards resolution. Thanks for your time and waiting for your response.
Nagarajan S